# uninstall and reinstall node

Tags: uninstall, node.js, vscode-extensions

I am using a Mac, Ventura and VSCode. I am teaching myself javascript and have installed **node** 3 times in 3 different places over the years,due to my own confusion. I am unsure how I installed them but think it was by terminal. The only reason I wanted it was to install Eslint, and to comply with a course. One **node** version is in my home folder and the other two are among my javascript files. I  presume I should:

1. uninstall Eslint and Prettier first, by Homebrew.
2. then to uninstall the latter 2 node versions, I should go to the relevant folders and uninstall with Homebrew?
3. Also no-one talks about install/uninstall Eslint and Prettier in VSCode. I presume the last thing to do is hit the uninstall button on these in VSCode?
4. Then I can reinstall node, Eslint and Prettier with Homebrew, then hit the install in VSCode?
5. I presume eslintrc.js, package.json and package-lock.json are generated automatically, and I do not need to save the old versions as I never really  used them?

I hope this makes sense, as I see there is no consensus on uninstalling **node**. Would appreciate any up to date advice.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I dont think i get you right, if you are trying to uninstall node.js? but if you are trying to do that you can do it by the following steps:

```
brew uninstall node; 
# or `brew uninstall --force node` which removes all versions
brew cleanup;
rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
rm -rf ~/.npm;
```

and then ofcourse you could also install it back with

```
brew install node;
which node # => /usr/local/bin/node
export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules' # <--- add this ~/.bashrc
```

But if you are just trying to uninstall a package globally like Eslint or any others package globaly you could do this

```
npm uninstall -g eslint --save
```

and if you want to know which ones you have installed you can run this in the terminal

```
npm list -g
```